# Calculating a nested sum

Tags: r, apply

I would like to compute in R something of the following kind:

[image: formular]

It is important that the summand could be any function f(y,x).

My approach so far is with nested for loops:

```
n <- 5
fun <- function(y,x){y^2 + sqrt(y*x)} # might be any function of y and x
sum_x <- c()
for(x in 1:n){
  sum_y <- c()
  for(y in 0:x){
    sum_y[y+1] <- fun(y,x)
  }
  sum_x[x] <- sum(sum_y)
}
sum(sum_x) # 147.6317
```

However, I do not like this approach. It's pretty ugly and becomes very inconvenient if lower and upper bound need to be more flexible. I thought about using `expand.grid` and then applying `fun` to it using `mapply`, but couldn't figure out how to express the nested structure of the sums. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: @akrun indeed, forgot to include x in the function arguments. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested `sapply` which will apply `fun` for only required terms and then take `sum` of it.

```
sum(unlist(sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) sapply(0:x, fun, x))))
#[1] 147.6317
```

Comment: I like this answer the most. Once one understands the structure, it is easily extensible and really just mimics the for-loops - but is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the `outer` product based on a function. This outer product will look at all combinations of two input variables and place the result in a matrix; it takes the following form:

```
outer(<rows>, <cols>, FUN)
```

In your case specifically, the following suffices:

```
n <- 5

fun <- function(x, y) {ifelse (y > x, 0, y^2 + sqrt(x * y))}

outer(1:n, 1:n, FUN = fun) %>% sum() # 147.6317
```

Since `y` ranges from `0` and `y` occurs in both terms, it defaults to `0` (by chance). Regardless, it's necessary in this case to include some form of indexing in the function definition since the nested summing of `y` is dependent on `x`.

Comment: Never used `outer()` before, great!!

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `outer` with use of `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
sum(outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(n), FUN = fun) * rowCumsums(diag(n)))
#[1] 147.6317
```

---

Or with `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
crossing(x = seq_len(n), y = seq_len(n)) %>%
   filter(y <= x) %>%
   transmute(out = fun(y, x)) %>%
   summarise(out = sum(out)) %>% 
   pull(out)
#[1] 147.6317
```

Comment: `fun(y)` could be any arbitrarily complex function of y, therefore this doesn't answer my question yet..

Comment: Yeah... You make no indication whatsoever that this should be more general than what you have posted.

Comment: @akrun I edited my question, hope the problem becomes more clear. I want to particularly avoid inconvenient indexing as in `sum_y[y+1] <- fun(y)` and obviously this complex nested for-loops structure.